# Every Other Row | Nth column of table in Haml

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Trying to make a table in HAML, and I have the following:

```
%table
  %tbody
    %tr
      %th{:rowspan => 2} Name
      %th{:class => "leftBorderS", :colspan => 5} Monday
      %th{:class => "leftBorderS", :colspan => 5} Tuesday
      %th{:class => "leftBorderS", :colspan => 5} Wednesday
      %th{:class => "leftBorderS", :colspan => 5} Thursday
      %th{:class => "leftBorderS", :colspan => 5} Friday
      %th{:class => "leftBorderS", :colspan => 5} Saturday
    %tr
      - 6.times do
        %th{:class => "leftBorderS"} A
        %th{:class => "leftBorderD"} B
        %th{:class => "leftBorderD"} C
        %th{:class => "leftBorderD"} D
        %th{:class => "leftBorderD"} E

    - @data.each do |row|
      %tr
        - row.each do |column|
          %td{:class => "leftBorderD"}= column
```

Css classes:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
.weeklyReview .leftBorderS {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.weeklyReview .leftBorderD {
  border-left: 1px dotted orange;
}
.weeklyReview .rowGray {
  background-color: gray;
}
.weeklyReview .rowWhite {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Sample Data being passed by the Rails Controller :

```
@data = [["adam", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["boy", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["charles", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["david", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["echo", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["foxtro", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["gamma", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["helio", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], ["indigo", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],]
```

The issue comes in in the last portion of the code.  I want every other `%tr` to be colored differently.   Currently the default is gray, but that still means that every other would have to be white, so I just made two classes to switch between the two).  Also To separate days, only certain `%td`s will have a solid left border, otherwise, they will have a dashed border.

For the HAML markup:

1. How do you step through every other row?
2. How do you apply only the `n`th instance to a data cell?

What I [have](http://codepen.io/specialorange/pen/GacAz), and what it should look [like](http://codepen.io/specialorange/pen/wFjzu).

I am mainly looking for the syntax, as it could be applied to data cells, rows, columns, or anything that requires parsing or stepping through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a CSS issue.

Use `nth-of-type` and forget about all those extra classes:

```
table {
  background-color: salmon;
}

th {
  background: salmon;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: salmon;
}
tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

You can also do it with columns:

```
td:nth-of-type(5n-3) {
  color: white
}
```

Comment: First off,  you blew my mind,  didn't know that CSS had Jquery-ish capabilities.  So mucho thanks there.  Would it be better convention to include `%col`s, or is accessing it by the nth td fine?

Comment: I would do nth td personally. Also, here's a [little tool](http://codepen.io/sacha/full/cAJEo) to help with the  confusing (at least to me sometimes) nth syntax.